mi codigo sobre el juego 3 en raya no compila
estoy empezando en esto de los códigos y ocupo codeblock y necesito ayuda estuve viendo videos y códigos que me compartían mis compañeros y no vi como arreglar este error no se que abra faltado o que puse de mas después trate de ver un video mas a fondo segui paso a paso y seguía igual no se si le falta una librería un punto y coma o algo similar aunque no creo ya que todo me parece en verde sin ningún error pero no pasa de eso
 #include <stdio.h>

    void loop (char c[3][3]);

    void intro_primera (char c[3][3]);

    void tablero (char c[3][3]);

    int main(){

    char c [3][3];

    loop (c);//activa todas las funciones inportantes y refresca la pantalla

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void loop (char c [3][3])
{
intro_primera (c);
tablero(c);

}

void Intro_Primera (char c[3][3]){
   int i, j;
char aux;

aux = "1";

 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        c[i][j] = aux++;
    }
   }
}

void tablero (char c[3][3]){
 int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (j < 2){
        printf(" %c |",c[i][j]);
        }
        else {
            printf(" %c ",c[i][j]);
        }


}
  if (i < 2){
    printf("\n-----------\n");
  }
  }

}


Qué mensaje de error te da el compilador y en qué línea?

ninguno solo no compila

¿Qué compilador estás usando? no conozco ninguno que termine sin terminar el trabajo o dar uno o varios mensajes de error.

De primeras hay tres errores en ese código por los que el compilador puede quejarse:
Uso de system() sin incluir su archivo de cabecera
  #include <stdlib.h>

Solo un apunte, dado que se sale del ámbito de la pregunta, usar system("pause") para simplemente evitar que se cierre la terminal es generalmente una mala práctica, es ineficiente, no portable (solo Windows) e inseguro. Hay alternativas, como simplemente usar getchar().
Llamada a función no definida (posiblemente un typo)

Declaración:     void intro_primera (char c[3][3]); -> Correcto
Llamada:         intro_primera (c); -> Correcto
Definición:     void Intro_Primera (char c[3][3]){...} -> Mal

C es sensible a mayúsculas, Intro_Primera e intro_primera son identificadores distintos. El compilador se va a quejar de que estás intentando llamar a una función no definida, simplemente:
void intro_primera (char c[3][3]){
   ...
}

Intento de asignar un literal de cadena a un char
En C las comillas dobles denota un literal de cadena, una cadena de caracteres terminada en null (\0). En cambio, las comillas simples denotan un solo carácter:

'1' -> Literal de carácter (char)

"1" -> Literal de cadena que contiene un '1' seguido de '\0' (char *)


En tu función intro_primera haces esto:
char aux;
aux = "1";

con lo que estás intentando asignar a una variable char un cadena de caracteres (char *). Debes hacer:
char aux;
aux = '1';

o directamente:
char aux = '1';

